# Android: Export images to zip

Tags: android, zip

Could someone help me, in my application I would like to export my images from gallery to .zip, but I have no idea what I need to do that. I will be grateful for any tips

Comment: `For non-developer/programming questions, see http://android.stackexchange.com.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is some basic zip code. Essentially create a string array containing all the image file paths you want to include in the zip and another string for the destination path of your zip file. Pass these on to the method.

```
public static void zip(String[] files, String zipFile) throws IOException {
BufferedInputStream origin = null;
ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFile)));
try { 
    byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(files[i]);    
        origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER_SIZE);
        try {
            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(files[i].substring(files[i].lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
            out.putNextEntry(entry);
            int count;
            while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
                out.write(data, 0, count);
            }
        }
        finally {
            origin.close();
        }
    }
}
finally {
    out.close();
}
```

}

Or alternatively, you can use the [Zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/) library.

Happy coding! :D

Comment: Thank you:) but I have one question, is any possibility to add to zip Bitmaps which I have stored in my DB, but without create files with images on SDcard? I am able to save it on SDcard, but, when I want to create .zip next, is unnecesary

Comment: No problem. Hmm...first how are you storing the bitmaps in your DB, I'm assuming you're storing their URI's there? And as far as I understand, you want to zip images using those URIs? Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: No, no, I have their Strings stored. I know that I could use bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream); but I'm thinking, can I just enter as fileOutputStream my zip folder? Is any possibility to create empty zip?

Comment: Ahh basically you want to zip your zip folder?  Should be fine I think. Empty zip, I'm not sure it's possible, I've tried before myself and it was quite a daunting task.

Comment: I was thinking about fileOutputStream as a empty zip

Comment: I created File where name ended .zip, and it looks ok. Thank you for your attention :)

Answer (score 0):

Use "
Easy Unrar, Unzip & Zip
"

Find the directory of the gallery, compress it

**EDITED**

Try this:

```
public static void compress(String[] folder, String compFile) throws IOException {
    BufferedInputStream origin = null;
    ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(compFile)));
    try { 
        byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

        for (int i = 0; i < folder.length; i++) {
            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(folder[i]);    
            origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER_SIZE);
            try {
                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(folder[i].substring(folder[i].lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
                out.putNextEntry(entry);
                int count;
                while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
                    out.write(data, 0, count);
                }
            }
            finally {
                origin.close();
            }
        }
    }
    finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya, but I need to do it in my application :)